# Fixing my Dual Boot Linux/Windows Computer

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot

I have a dual boot Acer Aspire One, after reinstalling Windows back to "original factory", the way it was straight out of the box, it now will not boot up at all.  It goes to the Windows start screen goes blank, and loops there infinitely.

Is there a USB tool I can use to figure out what went wrong and recover either my Windows or Linux partition with out having to do a complete reinstall?

Google lists a few, but I was hoping the community could point out a good one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite repair program is [SuperGrub](http://www.bootproblems.com/). It does not just fix Grub which it sounds like, but it can fix Windows as well.

You USB Pen drives bootable like [any other way](http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm) to do it.